# clearTimeout not working with multiple functions

Tags: jquery, timeout, settimeout, cleartimeout

clearTimeout isn't working in my code. I defined the variable global so every function should have access to it. Here is my code for better understanding (see comments in code):

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { /* SECOND CLICK IS AFTER ~2 SECONDS */
    var timeout;

    validation();

    mysql();

    function validation() {
        if (condition) {
            if (timeout) {
                console.log('timeout set');
            } else {
                console.log('timeout not set'); /* GET THIS BUT TIMEOUT MADE CHANGE AFTER DEFINED TIME */

            clearTimeout(timeout);

            if (timeout) {
                console.log('timeout set');
            } else {
                console.log('timeout not set'); /* GET THIS */
            }
        }   
    }

    function mysql() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.message').html('message for user');
                }, 7500);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: You're calling validation before mysql.  timeout will never be defined for validation at that point

Comment: Works as expected. `timeout` is set in `mysql()` which is executed _after_ `validation()`, hence in both `if (timeout) ...` cases `timeout` is `undefined`

Comment: `timeout` is scoped to the click method, it's scoped too low

Comment: What is the purpose of `validation`?

Comment: @Taplar - Yeah, that's possible. It depends on what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @Taplar I forgot to mention that it is for a second submit.

Comment: Right, and since it's scoped to the click, each click will have it's own timeout variable instance.  It's not shared between clicks.

Comment: @Taplar - I think you can post that as an answer now that we have confirmation from the OP that they want `timeout` to live between clicks. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder validation checks if a file has been selected

Comment: @Taplar is it possible to clear the timeout from first click?

Comment: If you raise the scope of the variable, yes

Comment: @Taplar how can I achieve that :)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript  Declare it outside of the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { /* SECOND CLICK IS AFTER ~2 SECONDS */
    var timeout;
```

The issue is your scope for `timeout`.  It is scoped to the click event handler.  So each time you perform this click logic, it creates a new instance for the context.  If you want to share a single timeout variable for all clicks, it needs to be moved to a higher scope, outside of the event handler.

For a more detailed question about variable scope in javascript, please reference: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)